# Loop through two tables and compare all the data in both the tables using MYSQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables :
**Table 1** :

```
Leader Code : 
Leader 1
Leader 2
```

**Table 2** :

```
Leader Code | Date | Member ID 
Leader 1    | Date | Member 1
Leader 1    | Date | Member 2
Leader 2    | Date | Member 3
Leader 2    | Date | Member 4
Leader 3    | Date | Member 5
Leader 3    | Date | Member 6
Leader 4    | Date | Member 7
Leader 4    | Date | Member 8
```

Now I want to compare these two tables and get the data insert into **Table 3**.

Table 3 :

```
Leader ID | Member ID | On Shift
```

When looping if the Team leader is on the **Table 1** then the On Shift should update to `Yes`. If the Leader is not in **Table 1** then it On Shift should update to `No`.

I tried using two `while loop`s also `foreach` but I'm unable to get the above update.
Please do check and correct me if i am in the wrong path.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried and we may be able to help